# Using Gtk.AlertDialog with Python

Tags: python, gtk

I'm trying to port an old GTK3 project written in Python to GTK4, and I'm having trouble with the deprecation of Gtk.Dialog. Specifically, I can find no example of how to retrieve user feedback from a Gtk.AlertDialog using Python. Does anyone know of one? I am trying to create a small dialog that would simply let the user bail out of an operation if desired. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The following works:

```
def delete_query(self, widget, data):
    selected_item = self.dropdown.get_selected_item()
    item_to_delete = selected_item.iid
    dialog = Gtk.AlertDialog()
    dialog.set_message("Caution")
    dialog.set_detail("You are about to take an action that cannot be undone. Proceed?")
    dialog.set_modal(True)
    dialog.set_buttons(["Cancel", "OK"])
    dialog.choose(self, None, self.delete_perform, item_to_delete)
   
def delete_perform(self, source_obj, async_res, item_to_delete):
    result = source_obj.choose_finish(async_res)
    if result == 1:
        < delete item_to_delete >
```